# How to run selenium inside docker container (python)

Tags: python, docker, selenium, docker-compose, dockerfile

Currently trying to learn docker. Cant seem to get selenium working inside container.

My docker compose file looks like this

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59
    ports:
      - 4444:4444

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:3.141.59
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=hub

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: "python main.py"
    depends_on:
      - chrome
```

My dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 4444
```

I have tried many ways, but currently my driver looks like

```
caps = {'browserName': os.getenv('BROWSER', 'chrome')}
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
                               desired_capabilities=caps)
```

After running

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

No matter what I seem to change, I always seem to get

```
app_1      | urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=4444): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb634bdab20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

If I just run main.py from my terminal after it will run no problem

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your service is "hub" so try running your code with the correct host like this:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
                               desired_capabilities=caps)
```